# How to pass list of objects to js function in struts iterator

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, struts2, struts

In a JSP page i use struts iterator

`<s:iterator value="categoryList" status="category">
    //other code..
    <a href="#" onclick="a_onClick('<s:property value="productsByOid"/>')"><s:property value="name"/></a>
 </s:iterator>`

I would like to call js function with list of objects as a param. And there I want to iterate this list and get the product properties (name, price). How do I do it ?

```
 function a_onClick(p) {
    alert('a_onClick');
    console.log(p);
}
```

On the console receives: [pl.model.Product@3270eb8a]

Fragments models class:

```
public class Category {
private Integer oid;
private String name;
private Collection<Product> productsByOid;
```

...
}

```
public class Product {
  private Integer oid;
  private Integer dostPno;
  private String opis;
  private String name;
  private String producent;
  private String price;
  private Category categoryByCategoryOid;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that? One possible solution is to put data into hidden fields and retrieve it in js.

Answer (score 0):

If your list is printed out in the jsp page then you can use a jquery selector and perform any action you wish by iterating.

If you want to load an object that exists in the stack (like the list you are iterating in the jsp) then you have to use the struts2 property tag to fetch that object from the stack. i.e.,

```
<a onclick='functionsName(<s:propery value="nameOnStack")'
```

maybe you need to add quotes also to the parameter above when passing its value.